# SPSS linear regression analysis

Tags: linear-regression, spss

Are there simple in-built SPSS functions for linear regression?

How do I get the residual series?

I want to perform a White test, Durbin-Watson (or inspect a correlogram of residuals), F-test for redundant variables and look at the Variance Inflation Factors.

I would have assumed that these would be standard functions for any stats package but I can't find them...

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am puzzled why you can't find these.  The are available in the REGRESSION procedure (Analyze > Regression > Linear) or GENLIN (Analyze > Generalized Linear Models) or ACF (Analyze > Forecasting > Autocorrelations).

Comment: Thanks for the  reply. I feel like a fool I still can't find them (other than DW, under statistics and residuals under "Save"). The regression is estimated under "Analyze > Regression > Linear" but where are the analysis options mentioned above?

Comment: Check the boxes in the Statistics subdialog for D-W and Collinearity diagnostics.  You can save residuals of various types via the Save subdialog and use the autocorrelation plots or other procedures to examine them.  See GENLIN for other statistics.  Also, you can get a Breusch-Pagan heteroscedasticity test from Regresion > Residual Heteroscedasticity Test if you have installed the R Essentials.

Comment: Apologies.  I thought White's test was included in GENLIN, but it isn't.  This technote explains how to compute it: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476748.  However, the results tend to be very similar to Breusch-Pagan available as described above.

Comment: Yes, BP and white are similar I don't mind which i use. thank you very much.